# SQL placement join with student, friend, package

Tags: join

**Issue:**

- You are given three tables: Students, Friends and Packages.
- Students contains two columns: ID and Name.
- Friends contains two columns: ID and Friend_ID (ID of the ONLY best friend).
- Packages contains two columns: ID and Salary (offered salary in $ thousands per month).

Write a query to output the names of those students whose best friends got offered a higher salary than them. Names must be ordered by the salary amount offered to the best friends. It is guaranteed that no two students got same salary offer.

**Code:**

This is the code that I have come up with but it does not produce correct results. Can anyone let me know why?

```
select TableA.name 
from
(select s.id,s.name,p.salary from students s inner join packages p on s.id=p.id) TableA,
(select f.id,f.friend_id, p2.salary from friends f inner join packages p2 on f.friend_id=p2.id) TableB
where TableA.id=TableB.id And TableA.salary>TableB.salary
order by TableB.salary desc;
```

Comment: Provide sample data for the tables. Also format the question so that the code is differentiated from the text. Is this for `mysql` or `sql-server`? Remove unwanted database tag.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your query you wrote `AND TableA.salary < TableB.salary`  instead of `AND TableA.salary > TableB.salary`.
Moreover I think your query can be written in a more synthetic way.
On MSSQL (but it works on MYSQL too, as query is very basic), you can try to use this one:

```
SELECT s.id
        ,s.NAME
        ,p.salary
        , f.friend_id, p2.salary as friend_salary
    FROM students s
    INNER JOIN packages p ON s.id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN packages p2 ON f.friend_id = p2.id
 WHERE p.salary <= p2.salary
ORDER BY s.id;
```

Output:

```
    id  NAME    salary  friend_id   friend_salary
    1   John    1000    2           1200
    3   Pete    800     1           1000
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE students (id int, NAME VARCHAR(30));
CREATE TABLE packages (id int, salary INT);
CREATE TABLE friends (id int, friend_id INT);
INSERT INTO students values (1,'John');
INSERT INTO students values (2,'Arthur');
INSERT INTO students values (3,'Pete');

INSERT INTO packages values (1,1000);
INSERT INTO packages values (2,1200);
INSERT INTO packages values (3,800);

INSERT INTO friends values (1,2);
INSERT INTO friends values (2,3);
INSERT INTO friends values (3,1);
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 1):

I used CTE for easy code readability. I am not sure whether it is fully optimized or not. But, it yields the result as expected from the question.

```
with std_salary as (
    SELECT s.id, s.name, p.salary 
    FROM Students s
    JOIN Packages p
    ON s.id=p.id),

    friend_salary as (
    SELECT f.id, p.salary 
    FROM Friends f
    JOIN Packages p
    ON f.friend_id=p.id
    )

SELECT name 
FROM
    (SELECT std_salary.name, std_salary.salary as own, friend_salary.salary as friend
    FROM std_salary
    JOIN friend_salary
    ON std_salary.id=friend_salary.id) as final
WHERE final.own<final.friend
ORDER BY final.friend;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in MS SQL

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM (SELECT students.id as main_id, students.name, packages.salary 
      FROM students join packages on students.id = packages.id) a 
JOIN (SELECT f.id as main_id1, p.salary 
FROM friends f JOIN packages p ON f.friend_id = p.id) b 
ON a.main_id = b.main_id1 
WHERE b.salary>a.salary 
ORDER BY b.salary ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution can also be done by CTE successfully, tried on SQL Server.

```
WITH cte_tbl_one (ID, Name, salary, Friend_ID) AS (
    SELECT Students.ID, Students.Name, Packages.salary, Friends.Friend_ID FROM Students 
    INNER JOIN Friends ON Students.ID=Friends.ID
    INNER JOIN Packages ON Students.ID=Packages.ID 
),
cte_tbl_two (ID, frd_id, frd_salary) AS (
    SELECT Friends.ID, Friends.Friend_ID, Packages.salary FROM Friends
    INNER JOIN Packages ON Friends.Friend_ID = Packages.ID
)

SELECT cte_tbl_one.Name FROM cte_tbl_one 
INNER JOIN cte_tbl_two ON cte_tbl_one.Friend_ID = cte_tbl_two.frd_id
WHERE cte_tbl_one.salary < cte_tbl_two.frd_salary ORDER BY cte_tbl_two.frd_salary ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

---

you have written 'where TableA.salary>TableB.salary' implying that you want to find rows where your salary is > than your friends. But the question asked was the opposite (to find names where the firends salary is > than your salary) so you can change that to 'where TableB.salary>TableA.salary' and it should work.

```
select my_name from
(select s.id as my_id,s.name my_name,p.salary as my_salary from students s 
inner join packages p on s.id=p.id) as my_tbl inner join (select f.id as 
id,f.friend_id as frnd_id,p.salary as frnd_salary from friends f inner join 
packages p on f.friend_id=p.id ) as frnd_tbl on my_id=id where 
frnd_salary>my_salary order by frnd_salary;
```